# React native Navigation 5 Hide bottom navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

I have getting this warning after updating React native Navigation 5 stack and bottom tabs to

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
```

The warning is :

Accessing the 'state' property of the 'route' object is not supported. If you want to get the focused route name, use the 'getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute' helper instead: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state

So what I want is to hide bottom tab and Add Plus Botton because it is a component, what i've done is the following and it was working fine. I know it's messy but it worked.

So I have

MainStackNavigator

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import TabsNavigator from "./TabNavigator";

const MainStack = createStackNavigator();

export function MainStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <MainStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <MainStack.Screen name={"Home"} component={TabsNavigator} />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

And I have TabsNavigator:

```
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { HomeStackScreens } from "./HomeStack";
import { ProfileStackScreens } from "./ProfileStack";
import SplashScreen from "../screens/SplashScreen/SplashScreen";
import AddButton from "../components/BottomTabCompnents/AddButton/AddButton";
import UserIconTab from "../components/BottomTabCompnents/UserIcon/UserIconTab";
import { Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabsNavigator = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { dangerouslyGetState } = useNavigation();
  const { index, routes } = dangerouslyGetState();

  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        style: {
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          height: 60,
          borderTopRightRadius: 20,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
          borderTopColor: "#fff",
          borderTopWidth: 0.5,
          shadowColor: "#909090",
          shadowRadius: 20,
          shadowOffset: { height: 10, width: 0 },
          shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStackScreens}
        tabBarOptions={{
          showLabel: false,
        }}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => {
            return (
              <Entypo
                name="home"
                size={40}
                color="#999999"
                style={{ position: "absolute", top: 5 }}
              />
            );
          },
          tabBarLabel: "",
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="SplashScreen"
        component={SplashScreen}
        tabBarOptions={{
          showLabel: false,
        }}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => {
            if (routes[index].state && routes[index].state.routes) {
              const screenName = routes[index].state.routes;

              if (screenName[index]?.state) {
                if (screenName[index].state?.routes) {
                  const ree = screenName[index].state.routes;
                  if (
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "WhereAreYou" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "AddTextPostScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "AddPhotoPostScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "AddMusicPostScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "AddMoviePostScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "PreviewMusicPostScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "ChatScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "SettingScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "AccountSettingScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "FriendsListScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "UserFriendsScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "HereNowScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "PostDetailsScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "PostPlaceDetailsScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "MessagesScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "ProfileFriendsScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "UserProfileScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "PreviewMoviePostScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "SearchFriendsScreen" ||
                    ree[ree.length - 1].name === "NotificationsScreen"
                  ) {
                    return null;
                  }
                }
              }
              if (screenName[screenName.length - 1].state) {
                if (screenName[screenName.length - 1].state.index > 0) {
                  return null;
                }
              }
            }
            return <AddButton />;
          },
          tabBarLabel: "",
        }}
        listeners={{
          tabPress: (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileStackScreens}
        tabBarOptions={{
          showLabel: false,
        }}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => {
            return <UserIconTab />;
          },
          tabBarLabel: "",
        }}
      />
    </Tabs.Navigator>
  );
};

export default TabsNavigator;
```

And HomeStackScreens

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Home from "../screens/HomeScreen/HomeScreen";
import NotificationsScreen from "../screens/NotificationsScreen/NotificationsScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "../screens/ProfileScreen/ProfileScreen";
import MessagesScreen from "../screens/MessagesScreen/MessagesScreen";
import SearchFriendsScreen from "../screens/SearchFriendsScreen/SearchFriendsScreen";
import SettingScreen from "../screens/SettingScreen/SettingScreen";
import AccountSettingScreen from "../screens/SettingScreen/AccountSettingScreen/AccountSettingScreen";
import FriendsListScreen from "../screens/MessagesScreen/FriendsListScreen/FriendsListScreen";
import ProfileFriendsScreen from "../screens/UserProfileScreen/ProfileFriendsScreen/ProfileFriendsScreen";
import ChatScreen from "../screens/MessagesScreen/ChatScreen";
import UserFriendsScreen from "../screens/UserFriendsScreen/UserFriendsScreen";
import UserProfileScreen from "../screens/UserProfileScreen/UserProfileScreen";
import PostDetailsScreen from "../screens/PostDetailsScreen/PostDetailsScreen";
import PostPlaceDetailsScreen from "../screens/PostPlaceDetailsScreen/PostPlaceDetailsScreen";
import HereNowScreen from "../screens/HereNowScreen/HereNowScreen";
import WhereAreYou from "../screens/WhereAreYouScreen/WhereAreYou";
import AddTextPostScreen from "../screens/AddTextPostScreen/AddTextPost";
import AddPhotoPostScreen from "../screens/AddPhotoPostScreen/AddPhotoPost";
import AddMusicPostScreen from "../screens/AddMusicPostScreen/AddMusicPostScreen";
import AddMoviePostScreen from "../screens/AddMoviePostScreen/AddMoviePostScreen";
import PreviewMusicPostScreen from "../screens/AddMusicPostScreen/PreviewMusicPostScreen";
import PreviewMoviePostScreen from "../screens/AddMoviePostScreen/PreviewMoviePostScreen";
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

export function HomeStackScreens({ navigation, route }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (route.state && route.state.index > 0) {
      if (route.state.routes) {
        const aa = route.state.routes;

        if (aa[aa.length - 1].params?.post) {
          navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: true });
          return;
        }
        const rn = aa[aa.length - 1].name;
        if (rn === "Profile") {
          navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: true });
          return;
        }
      }

      navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false });
    } else {
      navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: true });
    }
  }, [route.state]);
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="NotificationsScreen"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="SettingScreen" component={SettingScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="AccountSettingScreen"
        component={AccountSettingScreen}
      />

      <HomeStack.Screen name="WhereAreYou" component={WhereAreYou} />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="AddMoviePostScreen"
        component={AddMoviePostScreen}
      />

      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="AddMusicPostScreen"
        component={AddMusicPostScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="AddTextPostScreen"
        component={AddTextPostScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="AddPhotoPostScreen"
        component={AddPhotoPostScreen}
      />

      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="PreviewMusicPostScreen"
        component={PreviewMusicPostScreen}
      />

      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="PreviewMoviePostScreen"
        component={PreviewMoviePostScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="MessagesScreen" component={MessagesScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="SearchFriendsScreen"
        component={SearchFriendsScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="FriendsListScreen"
        component={FriendsListScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="ChatScreen" component={ChatScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="UserFriendsScreen"
        component={UserFriendsScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="UserProfileScreen"
        component={UserProfileScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="ProfileFriendsScreen"
        component={ProfileFriendsScreen}
      />

      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="PostDetailsScreen"
        component={PostDetailsScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="PostPlaceDetailsScreen"
        component={PostPlaceDetailsScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="HereNowScreen" component={HereNowScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

and ProfileStackScreens

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import ProfileScreen from "../screens/ProfileScreen/ProfileScreen";
import UserProfileScreen from "../screens/UserProfileScreen/UserProfileScreen";
import ProfileFriendsScreen from "../screens/UserProfileScreen/ProfileFriendsScreen/ProfileFriendsScreen";
import SettingScreen from "../screens/SettingScreen/SettingScreen";
import AccountSettingScreen from "../screens/SettingScreen/AccountSettingScreen/AccountSettingScreen";
import PostDetailsScreen from "../screens/PostDetailsScreen/PostDetailsScreen";
import PostPlaceDetailsScreen from "../screens/PostPlaceDetailsScreen/PostPlaceDetailsScreen";
import SearchFriendsScreen from "../screens/SearchFriendsScreen/SearchFriendsScreen";
import FriendRequestsScreen from "../screens/FriendRequestsScreen/FriendRequestsScreen";
import UserFriendsScreen from "../screens/UserFriendsScreen/UserFriendsScreen";
import HereNowScreen from "../screens/HereNowScreen/HereNowScreen";
import MessagesScreen from "../screens/MessagesScreen/MessagesScreen";
import FriendsListScreen from "../screens/MessagesScreen/FriendsListScreen/FriendsListScreen";
import ChatScreen from "../screens/MessagesScreen/ChatScreen";
import AddMusicPostScreen from "../screens/AddMusicPostScreen/AddMusicPostScreen";
import AddMoviePostScreen from "../screens/AddMoviePostScreen/AddMoviePostScreen";
import AddTextPostScreen from "../screens/AddTextPostScreen/AddTextPost";
import AddPhotoPostScreen from "../screens/AddPhotoPostScreen/AddPhotoPost";
import PreviewMusicPostScreen from "../screens/AddMusicPostScreen/PreviewMusicPostScreen";
import PreviewMoviePostScreen from "../screens/AddMoviePostScreen/PreviewMoviePostScreen";
import WhereAreYou from "../screens/WhereAreYouScreen/WhereAreYou";

import Home from "../screens/HomeScreen/HomeScreen";

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator();

export function ProfileStackScreens({ navigation, route }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (route.state && route.state.index > 0) {
      navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false });
    } else {
      navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: true });
    }
  }, [route.state]);

  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Profile"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="UserProfileScreen"
        component={UserProfileScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="WhereAreYou" component={WhereAreYou} />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="AddTextPostScreen"
        component={AddTextPostScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="AddPhotoPostScreen"
        component={AddPhotoPostScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="AddMusicPostScreen"
        component={AddMusicPostScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="AddMoviePostScreen"
        component={AddMoviePostScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="PreviewMusicPostScreen"
        component={PreviewMusicPostScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="PreviewMoviePostScreen"
        component={PreviewMoviePostScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="ProfileFriendsScreen"
        component={ProfileFriendsScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="SettingScreen" component={SettingScreen} />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="AccountSettingScreen"
        component={AccountSettingScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="UserFriendsScreen"
        component={UserFriendsScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="SearchFriendsScreen"
        component={SearchFriendsScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="FriendRequestsScreen"
        component={FriendRequestsScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="PostDetailsScreen"
        component={PostDetailsScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="PostPlaceDetailsScreen"
        component={PostPlaceDetailsScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="HereNowScreen" component={HereNowScreen} />
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="MessagesScreen" component={MessagesScreen} />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name="FriendsListScreen"
        component={FriendsListScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="ChatScreen" component={ChatScreen} />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

As you can see it is messy navigator. So I am trying to access the navigator state to control  when the bottom tab and the plus icon to hide because the position of the icon is absolute so when i hide the bottom tabs the icon still showing.

Any Ideas to how fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue and don't know why it was fixed but the only thing that I did is that instead of declaring everything in main App.js file I created them in other files and then just imported main Navigator

Comment: Any updates on this one?